# conversion of bitmap to vector image

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I need to convert a bitmap image (.png) into a vector in Adobe Fireworks. I selected the image using the magic wand, did modify marquee and then convert to path. However it just creates a blue color on the image. What am i missing?

Comment: That blue colour sounds like the results of your vector shape. Photoshop isn't great at vector work, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Johnny W is correct, the method you described should create a very clunky path and fill it with the foreground color.  Try playing with LiveTrace in Adobe Illustrator or Vector Magic http://vectormagic.com/